# Rails Production DB not what is in YML

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

The database exists as I have used it to create the tables however when trying to run the application I get the error
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (unknown database 'db/production.sqllite3')

Note that the database.yml has the following entries

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
   pool: 5
   timeout: 5000
   host <ip address>
   port: 3306

development
  <<: *default
    database: SCTP_dev
    username: <uname>
    password: <pwd>

test:
  <<: *default
    database: SCTP_test
    username: <uname>
    password: <pwd>

production:
  <<: *default
    database: SCTP
    username: <uname>
    password: <pwd>
```

nowhere do I see db/production.sqlite3
where does the system get the above production DB from?!

Comment: could you share your Gemfile?

Comment: Please describe your production setup. It is just on your local machine? Or for example on Heroku? If it is local, did you set up a production database next to the development database? (Rails uses a default naming convention if no names are specified.)

Comment: You write `production.sqllite` in one place and `production.sqlite` - is there a typo? (Maybe the pending edit fixes it?)

Comment: Oreoluwa: the gem file is source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'bcrypt', '>= 3.0.0'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end
gem 'simple_navigation'

Comment: Raffael: the MySql2 is on the same machine as apache. on an Ubuntu  16 LTS server. Database name SCTP is specified in database.yml file.

Comment: Have you run `rake db:create`?

Comment: You probably have a DATABASE_URL environment variable set.

Comment: Max:  I have created the database and made sure that I can access the database using the user id and password in the yml file.  Does using rake db:create update any other files in the system?

Comment: Frederick: I checked the environment variable DATABASE_URL, it is not set to anything.(empty)

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for your help. On running rake db:create it complained about the format of the yml file. it did not like the tabs. Replaced the tabs with spaces. the site works fine. Looks like if the database.yml file is not formatted correctly the run time rails will go with rails defaults.